# mac terminal error but not vscode's terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

so i have this program written in vscode and when i run it in vscode's terminal, it works fine but not when i run it on my mac's terminal.

the program is as follows:

```
def main():
    user_time = str(input("What time is it? "))

    # converting user_time to float
    converted = convert(user_time)

    if converted <= 8 and converted >= 7:
        print("Breakfast time!")
    elif converted <= 13 and converted >= 12:
        print("Lunch time!") 
    elif converted <= 19 and converted >= 18:
        print("Dinner time!")
    else:
        print("Bed time..")
            


def convert(time):
    # splitting number
    splitted = time.split(":")

    # finding decimal value of time
    converted = int(splitted[0]) + (int(splitted[1])/60)

    # returning to main program
    return converted


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

when i run it in the mac terminal, it shows this error:

```
What time is it? 7:30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mealtime.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "mealtime.py", line 2, in main
    user_time = str(input("What time is it? "))
  File "<string>", line 1
    7:30
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

is it just a minor issue and can anyone share a solution to this please

Comment: What is your Python version in the macOS terminal? If you run `python mealtime.py`, type `python -V`.

Comment: Thank you Constantin Hong for making me realise my mistake! By default, my terminal use Python 2.7.16 if I run python -V. But it uses Python 3.10.0 if I run python3. I've solved the problem now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python version in the terminal is different than in vscode.

If you run `python mealtime.py`, Check with `python -V`.

To ensure your code runs with python3, use `python3 mealtime.py`.